# Is it possible to use WA_DeleteOnClose attribute with a main window that has no parent?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qwidget, qtwidgets

I'm experimenting with the `WA_DeleteOnClose` attribute, which implements exactly what I need. Much more neat than doing the same manually. There's a problem, however: if I construct my `QMainWindow` that `WA_DeleteOnClose` is applied to with no parent, it doesn't get deleted on close. And if I do set a parent (the main `QMainWindow` of the application), the secondary `QMainWindow` in question loses its taskbar button, which is unacceptabe. How can I solve this dilemma?

Comment: What platform is that on?

Comment: I've added a test case to my answer, check it out and comment with its output.

Answer (score 1):

The `WA_DeleteOnClose` should work for any top-level widget. If it doesn't, it's a bug, or you're doing something else wrong, like perhaps running a nested event loop. A simple test for whether the window gets deleted would be:

```
QObject::connect(widget, &QObject::destroyed, [](QObject * obj){
  qDebug() << obj << "was destroyed";
});
```

> WA_DeleteOnClose is applied to with no parent, it doesn't get deleted

There's no code in the implementation of `WA_DeleteOnClose` behavior that is affected by the widget having a parent. As long as the widget is-a `Qt::Window`, it will be deleted. See [`closeHelper`](https://github.com/qtproject/qtbase/blob/dev/src/widgets/kernel/qwidget.cpp#L8253).

> the secondary QMainWindow in question loses its taskbar button, which is unacceptable

This probably applies to any `QWidget`, not only `QMainWindow`.

To confirm, does this test case not work for you? Let us know what the application output shows.

```
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPointer>
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QPointer<QLabel> label = new QLabel("Hello, world");
  label->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
  label->setAttribute(Qt::WA_QuitOnClose);
  label->show();
  app.exec();
  qDebug() << qVersion() << label; // will be null if label was deleted
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "This probably applies to any QWidget, not only QMainWindow" - right. "A simple test for whether the window gets deleted would be..." - Tried that before posting. It most certainly not get deleted, and it clearly is triggered by setting a parent. I'm oblivious of the implementation details, but it's a fact.